# sd maid navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have made a navigation drawer and tried a lot of things to change its layout and did a lot of research and i have made some good stuff, but i saw something nice in SD maid pro also in Samsung Watch On app they used a blue line when i choose an item in the navigation drawer this blue line appear on the left of the item as a signal that this item or tab or fragment is selected .
i believe they use state_activated but how it is done that's what i want to know so pl z anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SD Maids navigation drawer contains a ListView which is populated with objects that hold have a `boolean isSelected` value.

When an item in the list is clicked, the value of `isSelected` is set to `true` and all other items to `false`.

In the adapters `getView` method that value is checked and the list view entry is modified accordingly, in this case, a view with a set size and blue background is changed from `INVISIBLE` to `VISIBLE`.